# If we cannot use access-protected modifiers within an interface what are the options?

Tags: c#

As the title says:  If we cannot use access-protected modifiers within an interface then what can we use in c#?

The only answer found is to use an abstract class?

Comment: all members of interface are to be public. I guess with the newer C# spec coming - you can add some definition of methods in Interface.

Comment: Prateek what would be the name of this newer addition so that I might research it?

Comment: What *problem* are you trying to solve where you feel it is necessary to have access modifiers on an interface?

Comment: @Javacodeman113 - It will arrive with C# 8 - probably search for Interface Default Implementation - https://stackify.com/csharp-8-features/

Comment: Not having to have that new method on the interface be implemented on all the objects which implement the interface.  I haven't created the problem.  Being new I am determining which path to take on this currently.

Comment: Which I am assuming would require them to be implemented in each class independently.

Comment: Honestly, That just sounds horrid.  Why would you define an Interface, whose entire purpose is to guarantee that all classes that implement the Interface Implement all it's methods, only to selectively not implement some of the methods?  Hmm, I'm a Phillips Head Screwdriver, but I have a Flat Blade?

Comment: The entire point of an Interface is to give other users of your code confidence that if you say you Implement an interface, they can ask your code to do any of it's functions.  So much so that the compiler treats objects of different types that each implement the same Interface exactly the same, and if you didn't implement a method, there is a high probability that your code could crash.

Comment: interfaces are meant to define external usability of an object. For defining and possibly writing reusable internal logics, use an abstract class and subclass it for implementation.

Comment: I had simply misunderstood how the Interface is implemented, and now understand why using them should be avoided unless necessary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Interfaces don't allow member access modifiers but the interfaces themselves can have any access modifier valid for a regular class. This used jointly with explicitly implemented interfaces allows, in a way, member level access modifiers. Consider the following code:

```
internal interface IFoo
{
    void Frob();
}

public interface IBar
{
    void Blah();
}

public class Foo : IFoo, IBar 
{
    void IFoo.Frob() { }
    public void Blah() { }
}
```

And you essentially have the moral equivalent of a hypothetical:

```
public interface IFooBar
{
    public void Blah();
    internal void Frob();
}
```

Although it *is* true that there is no way around the fact that `Frob` must be implemented explicitly, at least as c# stands today.

Answer (score 3):

Interface members are required to be public.

If you need members with access modifiers that you are required to implement in the child class, use abstract members in a parent class.

```
abstract class BaseClass
{
    protected abstract SomeMethod();
}

class Child : BaseClass 
{
    // You will be required to implement SomeMethod() or declare abstract.
}
```